# Firestore: How do I update email and store it in my firestore collection as a single batch operation?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am writing react native project, where users can sign in with their `username` and `password`. As firebase authentication does not have the functionality to sign in with `username` and `password` I do a bit of a trick. On registration I store user's `email` in my `Users` collection along with other useful users info. So when a user tries to sign in with `username` and password, I go to my `Users` collection, look for the respective `username`, and fetch the corresponding `email` address. So in disguise, I use firestore method `.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` . Not ideal, but it does the job.

However, the problem is when a user wants to update his/hers email address to a new one. Then, I surely want to update the `email` value within my users collection, so I can perform proper sign in. Here is the code to update user's email:

```
const onChangeEmail = async () => {
    await firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(async function (userCredential) {
        await userCredential.user.updateEmail(newEmail).then(async () => {
          await updateEmailInFirestore(newEmail);
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error while updating email: ", error);
      });
  };
```

Where `updateEmailInFirestore` does the following:

```
export const updateEmailInFirestore = async (newEmail) => {
  if (!newEmail) {
    return;
  }
  await firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("Users")
    .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .update({ email: newEmail })
    .then(() => console.log("email was updated in user collection: ", newEmail))
    .catch((error) => console.log("error while updating email: ", error));
};
```

The above code works fine and does the job. However, the problem I am having is the following scenario: what if `userCredential.user.updateEmail` manages to execute successfully, but then `updateEmailInFirestore` fails or throws an exception? Then the value, which I have in my database wont be consistent with the user's updated email address and my login will fail misserably.

Is there a way that I can execute both `userCredential.user.updateEmail` and `updateEmailInFirestore` as batch operation, so that either both succeed or both fail? I have written batch operations before but they are along the lines of `const batch = firebase.firestore().batch();` and  my first operation is not related to firestore, but to firebase authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing much you can do when it comes to ensuring both the promises are resolved or not. Firebase Auth and Firestore are 2 different products so there is no concept like batched write. You can use a `Promise.all()` and ask user to retry in case either of the promises fail as shown below.

```
const updateUserEmail = async () => {
  try {
    await Promise.all([
      user.updateEmail(newEmail),
      userDoc.update({
        email: newEmail
      })
    ])
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Updating email failed")
    // prompt user to retry
  }
}
```

---

A better and widely used solution is to create an email of format `username@noreply.yourapp.com` and use that with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`. When a user updates their username (if you want to allow that functionality), then you just have to update the email to `newUsername@noreply.yourapp.com`. You won't need Firestore for email if you use this method.

Do note that you won't be able to use functionalities like verify email  as these email do not exist.